# Comparing cities polygon over time using Nightime lights

Tags: r, time, india

I am currently generating polygons of cities in India over time based on night light data. For this, I have been using the clump function in R and then converting them to polygons.

My issue comes when I create the cities for the next year. These new cities do not share any common properties from the cities created the previous year.

How can I compare changes in these cities along time?

[image]

For example, as shown in the image, in red are the city boundary in 2000 and in blue the city boundary in 2010. I need to somehow make sure that they share a common property so then I can compare them.

Comment: What makes all the parts of the red city a single city? Why aren't the little "islands" separate cities? You can overlay polygons using the `sf` package and that would show for this example that all the red polygons 100% overlap the blue and then you could use that to build a description of what's changed. Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Area is a common property. What common properties do you have in mind?

Comment: In this case, the red areas are different cities initially. As time passes they become a single unit. So basically the big red area consumed the smaller ones becoming all the same big city.

Answer (score 2):

These contiguous patches of light are economically defined agglomerations rather than administratively defined cities. With ongoing agglomeration growth, nearby settlements merge into larger units, i.e. fewer but larger patches of light.

With `st_join()` you can check which polygon in 2010 each of the polygons in 2000 intersects with. Assume that `shp2000` and `shp2010` are sf objects listing the polygons in 2000 and in 2010 respectively.

```
city_matches <- st_join(shp2000, shp2010)
```

Merging cities, however, impedes comparisons over time. Comparing each of the smaller red settlements with the larger blue settlement is certainly inadequate. The blue patch is a composite of the multiple red patches, which were differently large before they merged and therefore influenced the blue agglomeration to a different extent.

You could calculate the share of the blue agglomeration that intersects with each of the smaller cities via `st_intersection()` and `st_area()` and then weight outcomes according to that share. But as with alternative strategies, a comparison of these spatially variant and even merging agglomerations over time does not produce convincing results.

Your question on comparing agglomeration over time is more a theoretical rather than a technical GIS question. Which approach is the most appropriate depends on your research question. [Düben and Krause (2020)](https://www.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jors.12507) e.g. look at outcomes that are summed up over all pixels within agglomerations and therefore use constant agglomeration shapes in their baseline estimations.